# Capturar dados do Barramento

Tags: c++

Boa tarde.
Como faço para capturar dados do barramento quando se trata de vídeo ou imagens ? Alguma ideia ?

Exemplo:
Quando quero capturar dados de entrada do barramento posso utilizar std::cin, getline.

Mas se precisasse capturar dados de vídeo e imagens. 
Exemplo: Estou assistindo um vídeo pelo vlc, windows media player ou qualquer outro reprodutor de vídeo.

Seria possível com c++ saber quais dados estão passando pelo barramento de dados ?

Alguém conhece algum material que fale sobre isso ? 
Pode ser artigos, livros, vídeos.

Obs.: Preciso de referências.

Obrigado.

Comment: se for windows, vc precisaria saber a biblioteca de estrada e saída. Se for linux, em /dev/input tem os dispositivos do seu computador, teclado, mouse, video, display, power, etc...

Comment: Não conhecia esse diretório. Testei pro mouse no terminal ^^ Muito obrigado :D